# Highcharts legend is cutting off

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to plot a heatmap using highcharts api using the following chart options:

```js
{
    chart : {
     renderTo : 'chartContainer',
     type : 'heatmap'
    },

    title : {
     text : "abcd"
    },

    xAxis : {
     categories : []//categories,
     tickWidth : 0,
     title : {
      text : "Months"
     },
    },

    yAxis : {
     categories : []//categories,
     lineWidth : 1,
     title : {
      text : "xyz"
     }
    },

    colorAxis : {
     min : minValue,
     max : maxValue,
     gridLineWidth : 2,
     marker : null,
     tickWidth : 0,
     tickInterval : tickInterval
    },

    legend : {
     align : 'right',
     layout : 'vertical',
     verticalAlign: 'middle',
     symbolHeight : 250
    },

    tooltip : {
     enabled : false
    },

    navigation : {
     buttonOptions : {
      verticalAlign : 'top',
      y : -10
     }
    },

    series : [] //series data
};
```

But legend is somehow cutting at the top. Please check the following snapshot:
[Chart Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni1Nx.png)

I tried the different combinations of legend options mentioned in http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend
Also, tried increasing the height of the chart container. 
Still, the legend is still cutting at the top. 
Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Just tried to recreate issue, works fine in jsFiddle, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/qjwq5d30/ - are you sure you have posted all options? Can you update my fiddle with the issue?

Comment: I can reproduce it if I make the chart div shorter http://jsfiddle.net/qjwq5d30/1/

Comment: Thanks Paweł and Barbara. I figured out the issue. The issue was occurring because of the symbolHeight property. I reduced it to 150 and the legend stopped cutting off. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the issue got resolved. It was occurring because of the 'symbolHeight' property of the legend. I reduced it to 150 and the legend stopped cutting off.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the answer was to increase the legend:itemMarginTop to 20;

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by slightly reducing the font-size.

```
legend:{
  itemStyle: {
    fontSize: "10px"
 },
}
```

For this, I also had to change the `symbolHeight` to adjust it according to my font size.
Font size defaults to 12px.

Ref: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemStyle

---

Hope this helps. Peace.